# How to assign default value while performing concat on DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The `result` dataframe gets NaN value assigned to the column `b` which is not presented in dataframe `dfa`:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10], 'b':[10]})
result = pd.concat([dfa, dfb])
print result
```

Here is the result:

```
    a     b
0   1   NaN
0  10  10.0
```

Instead of `NaN` I would rather assign an integer value `0`. Could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `dfa` by columns of `dfb` and add parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
dfa = dfa.reindex(columns=dfb.columns, fill_value=0)
print (dfa)
   a  b
0  1  0

result = pd.concat([dfa, dfb], ignore_index=True)
print (result) 
    a   b
0   1   0
1  10  10
```

Comment: Would it be possible to reindex the `result` so the indexes are in sequential order like `[0,1]` instead of `[0,0]`?

Comment: Yes, add parameter `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!